# List isn't centering and wraps when the page exceeds 1 page of content

Tags: html, css

Here's my code :

```
ul {
     width: 100%; 
     position: relative;
     left:10%;
     margin: 0;
     padding-left: 100px;
}

li {
    float:left;
    box-align:right;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    width: 265px;
    background-color: #800000;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 5px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-left: 1px solid;
}

#list {
    background-color: #800000;
    padding: 0.02px 0;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width:70%;
    text-align:center;
    clear:left;
}
<ul>
  <center> 
    <li><a href="HomePage.html">Introduction</a></li> 
    <li><a href="Biography.html">Biography</a></li> 
    <li><a href="Songs.html">Brand New</a></li> 
    <li><a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a></li> 
  </center> 
</ul>
```

So I've tried playing with the float, width, text-align, box-align, and position all to no avail. I'm just trying to make a simple navigation list with boxes that stretch across the width of my page. I noticed that when I acquired a page of content the list wraps. So I believe it might have something to do with my percentages. I'm not sure though. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: We want HTML! We want HTML!

Comment: PLease, add HTML and create a fiddle.

Comment: 100% + 10% + 100px is much more that 100% width!  not sure if `box-align:right` is valid either: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-align

Comment: `<ul>
 <center> 
 <li><a href="HomePage.html">Introduction</a></li>
 <li><a href="Biography.html">Biography</a></li>
 <li><a href="Songs.html">Brand New</a></li>
 <li><a href="Pictures.html">Pictures</a></li>
 </center>
</ul>`